# limit digits in var multiplication total

Tags: javascript, numbers, rounding

I have this:

var ivu = (total3);
document.getElementById("project_pay_total_field4").value = "$" +  **total3 * 0.07**  ;

The multiplication produces this:

$10.080000000000002

--Its too long and when done in regular calculator it only says 10.08; how can i fix that?

Here is the function:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

function project_pay_detail() {
var rate = document.getElementById("project_rate_field").value;
var time = document.getElementById("project_time_field").value;
var total1 = (rate * time);
document.getElementById("project_pay_total_field").value = "$" + total1 + ".00";


var rate = document.getElementById("project_rate_field2").value;
var time = document.getElementById("project_time_field2").value;
var total2 = (rate * time);
document.getElementById("project_pay_total_field2").value = "$" + total2 + ".00";

var total3 = (total1 + total2);
document.getElementById("project_pay_total_field3").value = "$" +  total3 + ".00" ;


var ivu = (total3);
document.getElementById("project_pay_total_field4").value = "$" +  total3 * 0.07  ;
}


</script>
```

Heres is the form

```
<div id="project_pay">Pay Rate<input type="text" name="project_rate_field" id="project_rate_field" class="field" value="" /></div>

<div id="project_pay">Total Hours<input type="text" name="project_time_field" id="project_time_field" class="field" value="" /></div>

<div id="project_pay">Project Total<input type="text" name="project_pay_total_field" id="project_pay_total_field" class="field" readonly="readonly" value="" /></div>
<input name="project_pay_details_calculate" type="button" value="Calculate1" onClick="project_pay_detail()" /></input>

<br>
<div id="project_pay">Pay Rate2<input type="text" name="project_rate_field2" id="project_rate_field2" class="field" value="" /></div>

<div id="project_pay">Total Hours2<input type="text" name="project_time_field2" id="project_time_field2" class="field" value="" /></div>

<div id="project_pay">Project Total2<input type="text" name="project_pay_total_field2" id="project_pay_total_field2" class="field" title="0.00" readonly="readonly" value="" /></div>

<input name="project_pay_details_refresh" type="button" value="Calculate2" onClick="project_pay_detail()" /></input>



<div id="project_pay">Total<input type="text" name="project_pay_total_field3" id="project_pay_total_field3" class="field" title="0.00" readonly="readonly" value="" /></div>
<div id="project_pay">Ivu<input type="text" name="project_pay_total_field4" id="project_pay_total_field4" class="field" title="0.00" readonly="readonly" value="" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please please please format your code.

Comment: How does this have anything to do with Java?

Comment: this is Javascript not Java, I have updated the tag.

Comment: Ah, I see that someone removed the "java" tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using: *number*.toFixed(x)

```
var result = (total3 * 0.07);

document.getElementById("project_pay_total_field4").value = "$" + result.toFixed(2);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp

Comment: Note: `typeof number.toFixed(2)` is `string`. The problem is with the *display* of the value. `toFixed` addresses this with creating a *string representation* of the *number* to the specified number of digits after the decimal.

Answer (score 1):

```
total3 = Math.round(total3 * 100) / 100;
```

Comment: This is not correct even if it may work in some cases. The problem is with the *display* of the value. The default "to string" of a number implies no particular precision cut-off.

Comment: "The problem is with the *display* for the value". Trivial edge-cases include `total = 1` and `total = 0.1`. I've given an up-vote, but the answer should be clarified to reflect what is happening in this case as it differs from a fixed representation.